Google Tag Manager Server-side tracking in case of booking engine
I would like to set-up a server-side tracking for a restaurant. I have a main domain, where you can find information about the restaurant, but the table booking part is on a different domain. The second domain is related to a booking engine, so I do not have access to the code, in case of that I can not do the DNS settings and can not create custom domain for that.
What could be the solution or do I get it wrong?
Thank you in advance
I was trying to find information about server-side tracking in case of cross-domain measurement, but I did not find any useful information that is related to my case.

Server-side tracking doesn't really solve cross-domain tracking issues. It can help only in case you issue users an id which you keep track of before the reservation and after. So like if a user has to log in on your site before they will be able to make a reservation, and the reservation engine has an API by which it's able to let you know about those reservation, with the user ids you've issued. But even if you do, the measurement protocol is a very unpleasant thing to work with, plus it's quite hard to debug whether you use sGTM for it or no.
Generally, third party booking engines allow you to deploy your tracking on your instance of the booking. You should ask the booking engine developers how you're meant to track conversions and attribute them to traffic sources and campaigns. If yours doesn't, then you should most definitely change the booking engine since GTM is a pretty common and basic thing to provide support for when the nature of the service is effectively integrating into the user journey.
Sometimes the booking engine is served via an iframe. In that case, they typically issue window messages to the parent, so you don't need to deploy GTM on their side. You can just listen for the messages coming from the iframe.

Hello, thank you for your comment!
The client-side cross-domain tracking is working fine, so we can measure events, conversion ect. and we can see the user journey.
Because of many reasons (for example ending 3rd party cookies, data enrichement) we would like to switch to the server-side tagging. But I don't know if it is an option in case of using search engine, because I don't have the ability to do the DNS settings to create a custom domain for the server.

Third party cookies have nothing to do with cross-domain tracking in Google's case. Using server side GTM for your core first-party tracking is misusing it, essentially. It's possible, but it will increase the complexity and the cost of the tracking very considerably for no reason. In most cases, the only viable reason to use sGTM is for server-side third party conversions pixels in cases where offline conversion feed is not an option.
